# Quick SSO between moodle and codeigniter

Tags: php, session, jquery, single-sign-on, moodle

I am trying to implement some quick sso between moodle and a codeigniter app ..

I went through CAS and felt it to be complex or atleast not quickly graspable..

So i decided to do some sort of workaround.. and started by giving ajax request using jquery with username and password..

```
$(function(){
    $.post("/moodle/login/index.php", {username:'9535953595',password:'password'}, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Once this was successfull( i was able to go in moodle site without entering login details .. close to SSO i guess..) and since javascript will expose precious data like password.. i decided to use curl or zend http client to post data .. this worked to an extent .. it also returned me with moodle home page as result body

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://localhost/moodle/login/index.php');
$client->setCookieJar();
$client->setParameterPost(array(
    'username' => 9535952595,
    'password' => 'password'
));//POST
$response = $client->request('POST');//POST
print_r($response->getBody()); // MOODLE HOME PAGE HERE ;)
```

But there seems to be a problem in establishing a stable cookie or browser session.. the php way dint generate a cookie or moodle browser session .. and subsequent moodle urls were not accessible.. unlike ajax call which did create a real session..

can anyone suggest a good way to deal with this problem..

Answer (score -1):

The AJAX call is being made by the client browser so it creates a session between client and moodle. The curl is between codeigniter and moodle so that will hardly work.

I can only think of a working solution in this way is to have a middle page that has a hidden form with username and password and is submitted to moodle login page upon onload by javascript. This again won't be any more secure than the ajax one you have already tried.

It is highly recommended to use some SSO server. Those are pretty easy these days.